# How to apply a patch using svn export?

Tags: svn

I'd like to use svn to apply a patch from one version of Joomla to another.  I'm using a mac with Versions installed, but don't mind using svn on the command line.  So far, I've figured out how to generate the list of files that changed from one revision to the other, but I want to export those changed files to my working directory.  How does one go about doing that?  Do I need to save the diff output and process it using awk, or is there a command line option to pipe those files into an export command?

The diff command I'm using is: 
svn diff http://joomlacode.org/svn/joomla/development/releases/1.5@11255 http://joomlacode.org/svn/joomla/development/releases/1.5@11410 --summarize

Answer (score 12):

for creating a patch use:

```
svn diff > ~/patch.diff
```

for applying a patch use:

```
patch -p0 -i ~/patch.diff
```

Comment: Can the patch command be applied to a directory that isn't a working directory?  The directory where I am applying the patch is actually a working directory of a different repository.

Comment: as patch is a standard unix command It should work on a conventional (aka non-svn-workingcopy) directory

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as to the setup of your current repository and how much flexibility you have but following the [vendor drop process](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.vendorbr) as detailed in the red bean book might help.