# How do I merge two feature branches with subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control, branch

I'm working on a feature branch, which was forked from a development branch like a month ago.
My friend is working on another feature branch which was also forked from a dev branch.
Problem is, I want to get updated with some of his commits. 
I don't want to update him with my commits.
I don't want to wait until he merges his branch with the trunk.

I tried "dry merging" my branch with his but I get no results.
any help please? thanks

Comment: I think you should do the same as recommended in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317260/svn-merging-two-branches-together

Answer (score 3):

One way is to have your friend export a patch with the changes, and then you can apply the patch to your branch. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643868/how-to-apply-a-patch-using-svn-export) for more info on that.

On a side note, if you are planning to do this kind of distributed development long term, you might seriously consider switching to something like git. It has maybe a steeper learning curve than svn, but it makes dealing with multiple branches like this much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but because I'm here and looking for the correct answer and found the correct answer, the answer is in the "2-URL merge" described in great detail in the `svn help merge` doc

In short,

1. Do a catch-up merge from trunk on b1 and b2
2. `svn sw ^/branches/b1`
3. `svn merge ^/trunk ^/branches/b2`
4. Resolve any conflicts
5. `svn commit -m "Merging the changes from b2 into b1 to continue working on both features in b1"`

Comment: Thanks! Simple and does exactly what it should.
Note that the part with the catch-up merge is very important, I had problems because one branch was not *quite* up-to-date from trunk.
Also, TortoiseSVN has this feature - in the merge dialog, choose the second option: Merge two different trees

Answer (score 0):

You **have to read docs**, specially - `svn help merge`

In short: in SVN you can merge **any source** to **any target**, i.e you can merge some revisions from his branch into your. "Some revisions" means, that you have to use second form of merge

> This form is called a 'cherry-pick' merge:
>
> ```
>     svn merge [-c M[,N...] | -r N:M ...] SOURCE[@REV] [TARGET_WCPATH]
> ```